# CSS list-style with Font-Awesome toolkit

Tags: css

I will design a list with a Font-Awesome design arrows.
My code already works fine, but I will improve it.

```css
ul.long_arrow_right_red,ul.long_arrow_right_gold     {list-style: none;}
ul.long_arrow_right_gold li:before {content:"\f178"; font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;color:gold;}
ul.long_arrow_right_red  li:before {content:"\f178"; font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;color:red;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<ul class="long_arrow_right_gold">
  <li>Title
   <ul class="long_arrow_right_red">
    <li>Lorem</li> 
    <li>Epsum</li> 
   </ul>    
  </li>
  <li>Title</li>
 </ul>
```

**Questions:**

1. How to use an extra class which define only the color for the li icon? The text inside shouldn't change the color.

   Existing other css code, which I use for text coloring:

   ```
   .red{color:red;}
   .gold{color:gold;}
   ```
2. I think it would be better not do have duplicate following statements:

   ```
   font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;
   ```

   How to combine them with a different `content:` definition?
3. If you have other improvement ideas, please tell me them.

Comment: What determines whether a list should be red or gold?

Comment: @200_success It is the unicode for a long arrow right. You can see it [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/long-arrow-right).

Comment: I have updated my question. I have put the css-source file to the snippet. The css class should determine the color I think. Something like `class="long_arrow_right red"`

Comment: What I mean to ask is, why would you choose red or gold? Does it alternate, or is there some meaning to the color code?

Comment: @200_success I would propose another color for a child `<ul>`, but I want maybe later use other colors, too.

Answer (score 1):

Properly formatted CSS can make your styles vastly more readable, helping you find bugs as well as making it easier to work with.

This:

> ```
> ul.long_arrow_right_red,ul.long_arrow_right_gold     {list-style: none;}
> ul.long_arrow_right_gold li:before {content:"\f178"; font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;color:gold;}
> ul.long_arrow_right_red  li:before {content:"\f178"; font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;color:red;}
> ```

Should instead be something like this:

```
ul.long_arrow_right_red,
ul.long_arrow_right_gold {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.long_arrow_right_gold li:before {
    content: "\f178"; 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 1.5em;
    color: gold;
}

ul.long_arrow_right_red li:before {
    content: "\f178"; 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 1.5em;
    color: red;
}
```

If you want to have the code "minified" then do that before you deploy it, source code should aim for readability and maintainability, rather than length / character count.

Comment: Thank you. I have forgot to unminify my css code. Do you also could answer Question 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for my question one and two: using one class to make the arrows, and a second class for choosing the color.

```css
ul.long_arrow_right     {list-style: none;}
ul.long_arrow_right  li:before {content:"\f178"; font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;color:green;}

ul.gold li:before  {color:gold;}
ul.red li:before  {color:red;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<ul class="long_arrow_right gold">
  <li>Title
   <ul class="long_arrow_right red">
    <li>Lorem</li> 
    <li>Epsum</li> 
   </ul>    
  </li>
  <li>Title</li>
 </ul>
```